# How to join Many-To-Many table with extra parameter and extra condition with doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

First, I already use two one-to-many relation with a third entity with the extra parameters

But the complete schema is a little bit complex and i need to make a lot of join to get all my entity

And now the Query :

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('action');
    $qb->addSelect('location');
    $qb->addSelect('locationuser');
    $qb->addSelect('user');

    $qb->from('GestionLocationBundle:action',   'action');
    $qb->leftJoin('action.location',   'location' );
    $qb->leftJoin('location.users',   'locationuser'  );
    $qb->leftJoin('locationuser.user',   'user', 'WITH','user.idUser = action.refUser' );

    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('action.refLocation',$Location));

    $resultats = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The result is I get the list of all the user referenced by the selected action like this (the result is serialized in JSON ) :

```
0:{
    id_action: 79
    ref_user: 4875
    location:{
        users:{
            0:{user:{id_user:2, name:USER1}}
            1:{user:{id_user:4875, name:JAMES}}
            },
        id_location:10,
        name:LOC1
    }
}
1:{
    id_action: 78
    ref_user: 2
    location:{
        users:{
            0:{user:{id_user:2, name:USER1}}
            1:{user:{id_user:4875, name:JAMES}}
            },
        id_location:10,
        name:LOC1
    }
}
```

But for each action i only want the user referenced by the specific action.
How can i make this with the doctrine queryBuilder ?

PS : I cant post the schema picture because i don't have enought reputation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to give and appropriate answer while not knowing the schema, but in principle you could join the referenced `user` directly without using `location`:

```
$qb->select('action, location, user')
   ->from('GestionLocationBundle:action', 'action')
   ->leftJoin('action.location', 'location' )
   ->leftJoin('action.users', 'user')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('action.refLocation', $Location));
```

Comment: Maybe i have a bad relation schema because the entity action don't have a direct relation with the entity user. Only and integer with the reference of the affected user for this particular action.

I should change it ?

The problem is i have to apply symfony and doctrine to an existing Database so at first try, i was trying to keep it simple ...

Comment: @NoPr0n I would add this relation. It seems to be needed for your business logic and in general doesn't make the schema more complicated.